# Costliest operation of sorting

Tags: performance, sorting

What is the costliest operation of any sorting algorithm? Is it the swapping operation or the comparison operation?

I thought it was swapping but my friend thinks its the comparison. The only way I can justify that comparison is the costlier operation is that every element needs to be compared but not every element needs to be swapped (i.e if an element is already in the correct position, it does not have to be swapped). Therefore, overall in the bigger picture, there are more cheap comparisons than few costly swaps. But I am unsure of the answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: It depends. For disk-based data, the dominant factor is the I/O needed to bring the disk pages into memory. Once the pages are there, CPU is relatively for free. For small keys (ints) the swap may be costlier than the comparison. For very small element sizes, the memory (cache) locality could become dominant.

Comment: (continuing from wildplasser) ... which means for a list living on disk (or virtual memory), swapping is more costly.  But if the list lives in cache memory, then swapping and comparisons are roughly (order constant) similar expense, and then the cumulative cost of all swaps or all comparisons depends on which algorithm you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything is done into RAM a swap operation is atomically faster than a comparison operation.  (that's pretty obvious, 2 reads then a cpu operation versus 2 reads, 2 writes and everything in between including registry operations).

It clearly depends on your sorting algorithm, some do less comparisons because there are less elements, but swap comparatively more often.

Take quicksort that will do few comparison then swap pretty much everything and a simpler algorithm like bubble sort that with compare all the element with each other then swap less often. That also depends on the base array, if everything is already nearly sorted bubble sort won't swap anything but still compare everything while heapsort (for example) will still have to "swap" everything.

Finally the (avg number of swap operation)*(time cost of swap operation)/(avg number of comp operation)*(time cost of comp operation) is quite hard to estimate for an algorithm, and it's a lot more to extrapolate to all the algorithms.

I personally think that all in all the swap cost of any sorting algorithm is always higher than the comparison cost, but I can't back up that claim with any evidences (that's just a personal insight).

Comment: I don't quite understand the obvious part of swapping being cheaper when everything is in RAM :(

Comment: In a very simplified computer (not including the concepts of pagefiles etc because it adds a whole lot of randomness) if your array is in the ram in order to compare two values you have to load both into the registries then compare the two using the ALU. For the swaping you have to memorize the two RAM addresses in the registries then put both value in other registries then write in the ram using the address of the first value to write the second value etc. I could explain to you why it takes longer but I would have to explain to you other concept like cycles, microcode etc.

Comment: Take the thing above with precaution, that's for a simplified system, more advanced one use pipelining which add another layer of complexity. If you really want to know everything about this subject I suggest you to read and learn about computation structures/computer design because that's what really matter when thinking about costs of operations. If you've already some assembly that would be easier to explain.

Comment: (Also my example in the 1 comment is slighly flawed but the general idea is there : it takes more times to read and write in the ram than to only read and use the ALU)

Comment: @AdrienNK: Am I missing something, or doesn't your explanation demonstrate that *comparison* is cheaper than *swapping*?  Suspecting maybe you're written something other than what you intend?  (If not, then must admit I'm with Bugaoo and while the explanation makes perfect sense, I'm not following your conclusion!)